# Python: Return variables from one function to the other without rerunning the first function

Tags: python, function, return

I'm new to programming and new to python. I have made some small projects (rock-paper-scissor and hangman) without major issues. In an attempt to challenge myself I'm trying to make a game of 4 in a row without an example to base it of. I have created multiple functions which represent a piece/step of the game.

One of the functions (`get_player_input`) takes care of the user input. I ask the user to select a column. I then check multiple things (is it a int from 1 till 7 and is the column not full?). If the input is valid, I return the variables `column_select` and `free_places_column`. The reason I return these variables is because I want to reuse this information to "place a piece" on the gameboard with the second function (`place_piece`)

This is where I get lost. I'm able to use these variables with use of: `column_select, free_places_column = get_player_input()` However this piece of code reruns the function `get_player_input`. Resulting in the user being asked twice in which column he want to put a piece.

My code thusfar:

```
# The game 4 in a row

# Define the game table with 6 rows and 7 columns
game_board = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]


# print the game board
def printboard():
    print("|", game_board[0][0], "|", game_board[0][1], "|", game_board[0][2], "|", game_board[0][3], "|",
          game_board[0][4], "|", game_board[0][5], "|", game_board[0][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[1][0], "|", game_board[1][1], "|", game_board[1][2], "|", game_board[1][3], "|",
          game_board[1][4], "|", game_board[1][5], "|", game_board[1][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[2][0], "|", game_board[2][1], "|", game_board[2][2], "|", game_board[2][3], "|",
          game_board[2][4], "|", game_board[2][5], "|", game_board[2][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[3][0], "|", game_board[3][1], "|", game_board[3][2], "|", game_board[3][3], "|",
          game_board[3][4], "|", game_board[3][5], "|", game_board[3][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[4][0], "|", game_board[4][1], "|", game_board[4][2], "|", game_board[4][3], "|",
          game_board[4][4], "|", game_board[4][5], "|", game_board[4][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[5][0], "|", game_board[5][1], "|", game_board[5][2], "|", game_board[5][3], "|",
          game_board[5][4], "|", game_board[5][5], "|", game_board[5][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7")
    print()



def get_player_input():
    # set varaibles
    free_places_column = 0
    received_valid_input = False

    # Validate if player input is int and anywhere from 1 to 7. if not ask again
    while received_valid_input == False:
        try:
            column_select = int(input("Which column (1-7) do you want to drop the piece: "))
            if 0 < column_select < 8:
                for i in range(0, 6):
                    if game_board[i][column_select - 1] == " ":
                        free_places_column = free_places_column + 1
                if free_places_column == 0:
                    print("Column is full. please select an other column")
                else:
                    received_valid_input = True
            else:
                print('Please provide a number between 1 and 7')
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong input. Please enter a number between 1 and 7')
        return column_select, free_places_column

def place_piece(player):
    column_select, free_places_column = get_player_input()
    print("Going to place a piece in column", column_select, "and row", free_places_column)
    if player == "A":
        game_board[free_places_column - 1][column_select - 1] = "X"
    else:
        game_board[free_places_column - 1][column_select - 1] = "O"


while True:
    printboard()
    get_player_input()
    place_piece("A")
```

When I run this code this is the result:

```
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7

Which column (1-7) do you want to drop the piece: 1
Which column (1-7) do you want to drop the piece: 1
Going to place a piece in column 1 and row 6
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
| X |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

I have searched the internet and watched YouTube tutorials on retuning variables from one function to the other but I have not yet found how to deal with this. I found some this which could solve my issues but none of them seem the way to go for now:

- Make my variables global --> found many, many people telling other people not to do this
- Start using classes --> Still a difficult concept to grasp for me. Also kind of want to solve this without completely moving away from the choices thusfar
- Ditch the functions and make 1 big piece of code --> Trying to learn to use functions

I also wrote a small piece of code to remove some of the complexity. Hopefully making it easier to understand for myself:

```
def function1():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    print("We are in function 1")
    return a, b


def function2():
    a, b = function1()
    print(a, b)
    print("We are in function 2")


function1()
function2()
```

Result:

```
We are in function 1
We are in function 1
10 20
We are in function 2
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Best regards

Comment: Can you update the simple example at the end to show how you call `function2()`?

Comment: I see. Don’t call function1() yourself when function2() is going to do it for you. This is an imperative programming language after all.

Comment: A code review comment: you could simplify the printboard() function significantly with a for loop. Would be a good exercise for a new programmer :)

Comment: I managed to write it as two for loops. With the second for loop being inside the first for loop. I tried to paste the code here but I could not get it to recognize as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# The game 4 in a row

# Define the game table with 6 rows and 7 columns
game_board = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]


# print the game board
def printboard():
    print("|", game_board[0][0], "|", game_board[0][1], "|", game_board[0][2], "|", game_board[0][3], "|",
          game_board[0][4], "|", game_board[0][5], "|", game_board[0][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[1][0], "|", game_board[1][1], "|", game_board[1][2], "|", game_board[1][3], "|",
          game_board[1][4], "|", game_board[1][5], "|", game_board[1][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[2][0], "|", game_board[2][1], "|", game_board[2][2], "|", game_board[2][3], "|",
          game_board[2][4], "|", game_board[2][5], "|", game_board[2][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[3][0], "|", game_board[3][1], "|", game_board[3][2], "|", game_board[3][3], "|",
          game_board[3][4], "|", game_board[3][5], "|", game_board[3][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[4][0], "|", game_board[4][1], "|", game_board[4][2], "|", game_board[4][3], "|",
          game_board[4][4], "|", game_board[4][5], "|", game_board[4][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[5][0], "|", game_board[5][1], "|", game_board[5][2], "|", game_board[5][3], "|",
          game_board[5][4], "|", game_board[5][5], "|", game_board[5][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7")
    print()



def get_player_input():
    # set varaibles
    free_places_column = 0
    received_valid_input = False

    # Validate if player input is int and anywhere from 1 to 7. if not ask again
    while received_valid_input == False:
        try:
            column_select = int(input("Which column (1-7) do you want to drop the piece: "))
            if 0 < column_select < 8:
                for i in range(0, 6):
                    if game_board[i][column_select - 1] == " ":
                        free_places_column = free_places_column + 1
                if free_places_column == 0:
                    print("Column is full. please select an other column")
                else:
                    received_valid_input = True
            else:
                print('Please provide a number between 1 and 7')
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong input. Please enter a number between 1 and 7')
        return column_select, free_places_column

def place_piece(player):
    column_select, free_places_column = get_player_input()
    print("Going to place a piece in column", column_select, "and row", free_places_column)
    if player == "A":
        game_board[free_places_column - 1][column_select - 1] = "X"
    else:
        game_board[free_places_column - 1][column_select - 1] = "O"
   

while True:
    printboard()
    place_piece("A")
```

I just removed one line in your while True loop.

As you call `get_player_input()` in `place_piece(player)` function, there is noneed to call it twice.

You want both functions to be executed in a given order, but since the `get_player_input()` is embedded in the code of `place_piece(player)`, you just need to execute `place_piece(player)`.

To use your simple example:

```
def function1():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    print("We are in function 1")
    return a, b


def function2():
    a, b = function1()
    print(a, b)
    print("We are in function 2")
```

If you call only `function2()`, the ouput is:

```
We are in function 1
10 20
We are in function 2
```

If you call only `function1()`, the output is:

```
We are in function 1
```

If you call `function1()` and then `function2()`, the output is:

```
We are in function 1
We are in function 1
10 20
We are in function 2
```

And `function2()` and then `function1()`:

```
We are in function 1
10 20
We are in function 2
We are in function 1
```

To get what you want by calling two functions in your code, you need:

```
def function1():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    print("We are in function 1")
    return a, b


def function2(a,b):
    print(a, b)
    print("We are in function 2")

a, b = function1()

function2(a,b)
```

And you get:

```
We are in function 1
10 20
We are in function 2
```

With your full code:

```
# The game 4 in a row

# Define the game table with 6 rows and 7 columns
game_board = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]


# print the game board
def printboard():
    print("|", game_board[0][0], "|", game_board[0][1], "|", game_board[0][2], "|", game_board[0][3], "|",
          game_board[0][4], "|", game_board[0][5], "|", game_board[0][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[1][0], "|", game_board[1][1], "|", game_board[1][2], "|", game_board[1][3], "|",
          game_board[1][4], "|", game_board[1][5], "|", game_board[1][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[2][0], "|", game_board[2][1], "|", game_board[2][2], "|", game_board[2][3], "|",
          game_board[2][4], "|", game_board[2][5], "|", game_board[2][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[3][0], "|", game_board[3][1], "|", game_board[3][2], "|", game_board[3][3], "|",
          game_board[3][4], "|", game_board[3][5], "|", game_board[3][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[4][0], "|", game_board[4][1], "|", game_board[4][2], "|", game_board[4][3], "|",
          game_board[4][4], "|", game_board[4][5], "|", game_board[4][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("|", game_board[5][0], "|", game_board[5][1], "|", game_board[5][2], "|", game_board[5][3], "|",
          game_board[5][4], "|", game_board[5][5], "|", game_board[5][6], "|")
    print("- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -")
    print("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7")
    print()



def get_player_input():
    # set varaibles
    free_places_column = 0
    received_valid_input = False

    # Validate if player input is int and anywhere from 1 to 7. if not ask again
    while received_valid_input == False:
        try:
            column_select = int(input("Which column (1-7) do you want to drop the piece: "))
            if 0 < column_select < 8:
                for i in range(0, 6):
                    if game_board[i][column_select - 1] == " ":
                        free_places_column = free_places_column + 1
                if free_places_column == 0:
                    print("Column is full. please select an other column")
                else:
                    received_valid_input = True
            else:
                print('Please provide a number between 1 and 7')
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong input. Please enter a number between 1 and 7')
        return column_select, free_places_column

def place_piece(player,column_select,free_places_column):
    print("Going to place a piece in column", column_select, "and row", free_places_column)
    if player == "A":
        game_board[free_places_column - 1][column_select - 1] = "X"
    else:
        game_board[free_places_column - 1][column_select - 1] = "O"
   

while True:
    printboard()
    column_select, free_places_column = get_player_input()
    place_piece("A",column_select, free_places_column)
```

Output:

```
Which column (1-7) do you want to drop the piece: 2
Going to place a piece in column 2 and row 6
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   | X |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
| X | X | X |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7

Which column (1-7) do you want to drop the piece: 3
Going to place a piece in column 3 and row 4
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   | X |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
|   |   | X |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
| X | X | X |   |   |   |   |
- - + - + - + - + - + - + - -
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7

Which column (1-7) do you want to drop the piece:
```

Comment: Thanks! , That is quite an easy solution to my issue. This does reduce the readability of the code quite a lot (for my beginner eyes anyway) as the while True loop previously showed  the steps of the game quite clearly. With this solution it looks like there are steps missing (which in reality are being called by another function. Any way around that?

Comment: Well I edited with a "two calls" version of your first code. I hope that works!

Comment: Yes that definitely works! Just to be sure, in none coding language, is this is what's happing in your version of the simple example: We say variable A and B  = delivered by function1 (by return). We then say function2 here you have variable A and B. Go and execute. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you assign the "return" value(s) of one function to variable A and B. And then you pass A and B as "arguments" or another function(A,B). Then you get A,B from func1 and return line, and C from return of func2 feeded with A,B.